# PuTTY use agent forwarding for chain of servers

Tags: ssh, putty

I failed to configure AgentForwarding with PuTTY :(

PuTTY is newest 0.61 version. I have created public/private key pair for PuTTY, converted them to openssh format, added them to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys on both host1 and host2. On both hosts in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

On both hosts /root/.ssh/config contains

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
```

In PuTTY configuration, option Connection/SSH/Auth/Allow agent forwarding [x] is checked on.

Whan I'm running pagent.exe with loaded keyfile, I can connect to host1 and host2 without password. But when I am connected to host1 and try to `ssh root@host2`, I'm prompted for password. Variable $SSH_AUTH_SOCK is not set in my host1 session. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Agent forwarding may be disabled globally on the host1 in sshd_config. Have you ruled this out yet?

Comment: AllowAgentForwarding is on by default. I wrote this to config file and restarted ssh service, but nothing have changed. I've updated question

Comment: Are the keys passphrase protected? Have you loaded them into Pageant and entered the passphrase there?

Comment: No passphrase. Key is loaded in pagent, I can ssh to host1 or host2 without entering the password, but when I ssh to host2 from host1 session password is asked.

Comment: What version of ssh are you using ?

Comment: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in `screen` application. It was started by PuTTY on remove host with `screen -d -RR`(Connection/SSH/Remote Command). I found solution [here](http://www.deadman.org/sshscreen.php) and slightly modified it:

~/.bashrc:

```
# Correct screen and tmux behavior with ssh-agent
parent="$(ps -o comm --no-headers $PPID)"

case $parent in
sshd)
        keep_vars="SSH_CLIENT SSH_TTY SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_CONNECTION DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"
        touch $HOME/.ssh/keep_vars
        chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/keep_vars
        for i in $keep_vars; do
                 (eval echo export $i=\\\'\$$i\\\')
        done > $HOME/.ssh/keep_vars
;;
screen|tmux)
        source $HOME/.ssh/keep_vars
;;
esac
# This command must be run from shell within detached and re-attached screen session
# to interact with ssh-agent properly
alias fixssh="source $HOME/.ssh/keep_vars"
alias ssh="source $HOME/.ssh/keep_vars; ssh"
```

Every time I connect, ssh agent variables are stored in `$HOME/.ssh/keep_vars`.
Every newly opened window in screen can immediately connect to other machines with my key - it receive proper variables from screen. In old windows, I need to type `fixssh` and then try connecting.

Comment: I do not understand the need for the line 'alias ssh="source $HOME/.ssh/keep_vars; ssh"'

Comment: I de-attach screen session and close ssh connection. Then I establish ssh connection again and re-attach screen session. SSH_AUTH_SOCK changed, but running in screen shell doesn't know about it.

Comment: As the original question did not mention `screen` at all, there were no chances for anyone to provide a correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since $SSH_AUTH_SOCK is not set, its likely either a problem with putty/pagent, or sshd itself.

You can put sshd into debug mode easily enough. Log into the server (this can be safely done over ssh, as long as you remember to restart sshd after you are done) and stop sshd (via your init scripts). Then run:

/usr/sbin/sshd -Dddd

(-D for foreground mode, -ddd for verbose debugging)

Try to connect via putty again, and watch the output from sshd. If putty is sending the keys for agent forwarding, you should see something about auth-agent-req@openssh.com. If you don't see that, then putty is not properly sending the key along for agent forwarding/requesting agent forwarding.

That should narrow down where the issue lies. You can also run 'ssh -vvv' from host1 for verbose debugging output while trying to ssh to host2.

(At this point, please remember to ctrl+C the foreground sshd process and restart it from your init scripts, otherwise you'll be locked out of your server!)

Comment: LogLevel DEBUG3 in sshd_config to the rescue! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I claim that Putty is using a different key than the one that is loaded into Pageant. Set a passphrase on your key, load it into Pageant and see if Putty still asks for a passphrase when connecting.